# Page previewing issue in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have deployed my first page in Sitecore. But it is not rendered perfectly in Content editor preview mode.

**Original html:**
[image]

There is a nav menu and a banner below it. Behind them is a white transparent overlay & behind the overlay is a graffiti background image.

**View from Experience editor:**
[image]

The settings icon went offset. The white overlay is now above the Sitecore menu preventing the edits.

> Error in browser console:
>   Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is
>   not a function - prototype.js:5734
>   Uncaught TypeError:
>   element.attachEvent is not a function - prototype.js:5653

**View in Content Editor:**
[image]

It is rendered as if for a tablet, as you see the menu got shifted to the icon. I understand, it is because of the dimensions of the preview panel.
But, if this is the case, how will an author be able to edit/view the correct design.

Prototype.js is not a file being used by the site. So, it must be from Sitecore's.

Im guessing , certain CSS props, aren't being respected (Like position, transformnation).

Is this a bug. How to fix this. I have checked in different browsers (IE, chrome & firefox). It's the same

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running into a conflict with prototype.js. Sitecore uses this in the experience editor.

If you are using jQuery in your site, there is a kb article about that here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/286042

To fix the issue, you need to run jQuery in no conflict mode. There are a few ways of doing that. Here is a simple example:

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable now has the prototype meaning, which is a shortcut for
// document.getElementById(). mainDiv below is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
window.onload = function() {
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```

You can find more on the jQuery website: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

You also need to be careful with your CSS - don't absolutely position elements to the top of your browser, always make sure they are relative to a container so that the Sitecore EE DOM elements can be added and positioned correctly.

Comment: I have 2 similar questions. (i)The designs are already developed by another team (which is usually the case. isn't it). If there are many .js files for each page, does the no-conflict declaration need to be done in every js file. (ii)The designer doesn't know that the page is viewed in another interface like Sitecore, so positioning elements keeping sitecore in mind is out of question. How to go about it then. Please advise.

Comment: You don't really have a choice about positioning elements. The front end team must work with Sitecore not against it, it you want the Experience Editor to be a nice _Experience_ :)  As for JS - it all depends on how they are writing their JS. TBH - a good front end team should be writing using AND modules or closures or something like that which will allow them to implement no-conflict mode easily. Alternatively - I believe this no conflict issue has been fixed in later versions.